# Why symphony/finder ignore files?

Tags: docker

I run **docker** php-alpine and exec codeception tests. But it's shows only small part of all tests. After long debugging i find problem: `Symfony\Component\Finder` not see all files only in 1 directory. IDK why. All files are `*.php`

`count(Finder::create()->in($path))` - 9/61 files

`count(scandir($path))` - 63: 63 - 2 (`['.','..']`) = 61 files

In others directories it's work normaly

Comment: Is this really full code? How does your `$path` looks like? Maybe it find only first depth files?

Comment: ```var_dump(count(scandir((__DIR__ . '/../../../../../../app/tests/unit'))));```
```var_dump(count(Finder::create()->files()->in((__DIR__ . '/../../../../../../app/tests/unit'))));```

Comment: How much there is files? Because scandir finds dirs and files, while you tell Finder to find only files

Comment: 61 "*Cest.php" files